# bash [second-argument: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, automation, command, mkdir

So I ran into a problem when automating my projects with bash shell script and python...

I want to write a program that can help me to create new repositories using GitHub. However, I ran into this problem when executing my code.

Essentially, what I want to do is run '`create repo repo-name`' and create a new github repository locally.

```
function create() {
    cd
    cd path/to/python/file
    python3 gh-create-command.py $*
    if [$1 == 'repo']
    then
        <creating repository>
    fi
}
```

But when I run this code I get the error, `bash: [repo: command not found`.

Can someone help me out here?

Please reply if I should post the complete code.

Thanks.

### EDIT: FULL CODE

`function create() {
    cd
    cd path/to/python/file
    python3 gh-create-command.py $*
    echo $1
    if [ '$1' == 'repo' ]
    then
        cd
        cd path/
        mkdir $2
        cd $2
        touch README.md
        git init
        cd ..
        cd path/to/python/file
        python3 gh-create-online-repo.py $*
        git remote add origin 'https://github.com/advaitvariyar/$2.git'
        git add .
        git commit -m "initial commit"
        git push -u origin master
        code .
    fi
}`

output: repo

Comment: You're missing a space after the `[`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing whitespaces, it should be:

```
if [ $1 == 'repo' ]
```

And it's a good practice to quote all of your variables to avoid  [word
splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting):

```
if [ "$1" == 'repo' ]
```

and to avoid Bashisms to make your code more portable. Use:

`create() {`

and

`if [ "$1" = 'repo' ]`

Comment: Hi, I added the whitespace, but the contents inside the if statement are still not running.

Comment: That means that `"$1"` is not equal to `'repo'`. Check its value just before if line: `echo "$1"`.

Comment: I did it and it gave repo in the terminal

Comment: Can you show your updated script by editing the question and post the output you got?

Comment: Sure

`function create() {
    cd
    cd path/to/python/file
    python3 gh-create-command.py $*
    echo $1
    if [ '$1' == 'repo' ]
    then
        cd
        cd path/
        mkdir $2
        cd $2
        touch README.md
        git init
        cd ..
        cd path/to/python/file
        python3 gh-create-online-repo.py $*
        git remote add origin 'https://github.com/advaitvariyar/$2.git'
        git add .
        git commit -m "initial commit"
        git push -u origin master
        code .
    fi
}`

output: repo

Comment: This is not `by editing the question`.

Comment: Make sure that there are no leading whitespaces before `repo`. Try with `if [ "$1" == ' repo' ]`

Comment: You cannot use `'` (single quotes) - it will not deferefence a variable, you have to use `"` (double quotes) as I said in my answer.